# 'dict object' has no attribute 'json' in ansible

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

Ansible Playbook Code:

```
  - name: Fetching Blueprint ID from VRA
    ansible.builtin.uri:
      url: https://myvrahost/catalog-service/api/consumer/entitledCatalogItemViews?%24filter=name+eq+%27myblueprinttest%27
      method: GET
      validate_certs: no
      return_content: yes
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
        Authorization: Bearer {{ token.json['id'] }}
    register: bpid

  - name: Print BP_ID
    debug:
      msg: "{{ bpid.json }}"
```

Error:
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'json'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/vra_testing/vm_deploy_test1.yaml': line 48, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Print BP_ID\n    ^ here\n"}

msg: "{{ bpid.json }}"

Comment: I can't tell from error message if the error is from the token or bpid.  Can you print both (sanitize as needed).  The former requires the variable being set, latter depends on the result of the first task.

Comment: Output for fetching bpid

TASK[Fetching Blueprint ID from VRA] 
ok: [localhost] => (item = 1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store",
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content": "{\"links\":[],\"content\":[{\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    "content_length": "1209",
    "content_type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "item": "1",
    "json": {
        "content": [{
                "@type": "ConsumerEntitledCatalogItemView",
                "catalogItemId": "ce46f750-339a-4b95-a391-8ef157ebc5b8",

Comment: ERROR

task path: /home/username / vra_testing / vm_deploy_test1.yaml: 48
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'json'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/username/vra_testing/vm_deploy_test1.yaml': line 48, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Print BP_ID\n    ^ here\n"
}

Comment: If you are registering in a loop in your real code but showing us an example without a loop in your question, that's not a [mre] anymore. So basically, you also need to loop on `bpid.results` in your debug and display `item.json`.

Comment: Next time when we ask for clarifications please edit the question and update it with the new information instead of a comment.  It is much easier to read.

Comment: Sure Allan.....

Answer (score 0):

Removed the loop from bpid.results worked liked a charm!

Thanks!